# Tag rename request: mathematica to wolfram-mathematica

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Since the vast majority of *Mathematica* users have moved to [the dedicated site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) many of the remaining uses of [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) are incorrect.  I frequently retag questions that are tagged [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) when they should be tagged [math](/questions/tagged/math), and in fact they are often tagged with both.  To mitigate this problem I am requesting that [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) be renamed to [wolfram-mathematica](/questions/tagged/wolfram-mathematica) to make it clear that it is not a synonym for math.

Comment: People are using the tag wrong because they think `mathematica == math`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes.  I can find many examples if that is required, but I'd rather not.

Comment: `mathematica` already has several synonyms, including `wolfram`.  It could take awhile.

Comment: In other news, if people can't distinguish between math and mathematica, I don't know that there's much hope for their maths questions.

Comment: @Robert http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica (possible explanation that does not involve stupidity)

Comment: Wow, glad you found a *great* constructive solution to the mathematica tag problem. :-)

Comment: @RobertHarvey People can be good at math even without having a perfect grasp of the English language. Not everyone's a native speaker of English, and mathematica may be close to how or exactly how they say math in their language.

Comment: @ThorX89: That "not a native speaker" excuse only goes so far.  We have these things call proofreaders.  And spelling/grammar checkers.  And dictionaries.

Comment: @Martijn Try, try again, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, that was easy.  The cache even got invalidated, so the change showed up immediately.  Usually, on tag "role-reversals," it takes awhile for the question lists to update.

Someone's been playing with the SE code base.